# Mongoose-TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to add a post and then if succeeded, push it's ref to user collection. That's how I'm doing this:

That's mine "app.js" file which contains User and Post Schema.

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/blog_demo", {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useFindAndModify: false
 });
//post-{title,content}
var postSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    content:String
});
var Post=mongoose.model('Post',postSchema);
//user-{email,name}
var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    name:String,
    posts:[postSchema]
});
var User=mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

//Create data
var newUser=new User({
    email:'heromi@gmail.com',
    name:'heromi'
});
newUser.posts.push({
    title:'reflections on apples',
    content:'They are delicious'
});
newUser.save(function(err,user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log(user)
    }
});
User.find({name:'heromi'},function(err,user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        user.posts.push({
            title:'3 thing I hate',
            content:'voldemort,voldemort,voldemort'
        });
        user.save(function(err,user){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }else{
                console.log(user)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is when I'm trying to push the post to user.

```
user.posts.push(..)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thanks for your time.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.find` returns an array of documents who matche with you query object. If you want only one result, use `User.findOne` instead or check if `user.length > 0` and try `user[0].posts.push(...)`